# NHibernate not-null attribute has no effect

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nullable

I'm trying to add a column to an existing table. I added a property to the mapping :

```
<property name="SelectionId" column="selection_id" not-null="true"/>
```

When I open the session, the new column is created, however the `not-null` attribute is not taken into account : the new column is nullable.

I realize you need to specify a default value when adding a non-nullable column, but there is no `default` or `default-value` attribute for the `<property>` element... And anyway, I *don't want* a default value on this column : I want to set a specific value (0) for it on existing rows, but subsequent inserts will *have* to specify the value explicitly.

How can I make it work ? Do I have to do it manually in SQL ?

BTW, the underlying DBMS is SQLite, which has very limited support for `ALTER TABLE` (only add column and rename table are supported)...

Comment: this may be a bug, how you searched the jira if it is already reported?

Comment: apparently it is offline... (http://jira.nhforge.org/)

Comment: Something like NHibernate Profiler may be able to show you the alter that is sent so you can verify that no not-null is being sent.  After that a trip to JIRA and if it's not there and you feel up to it confirmation this works/does not work under another db like MS SQL Server or whatever you have available would be worthwhile.  Then you can report it yourself.

Comment: Are you trying to generate a database at runtime (e.g., for integration tests) and finding that the column in the resulting database is nullable?

Comment: It seems jira.nhforge.org is always down.  :(

Comment: @apollodude217, the database already exists, I'm trying to add a new column. When I add a new property to the NH mapping, the column is created, but without the NOT NULL constraint

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a SQLite thing, not NHib. I only use SQLite for testing, and with std in memory connection string and I've noticed this issue also. SQLServer is generated properly. If SQLite is your main db you might do better checking with their mailing list to see if some alternate connection string will fix it. HTH